# Can I make an async call in a redux reducer if don't need the response back?

Tags: react-native, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I know we cannot update the redux state with the response from an async function. But I want to only make an async call and don't require some response back. For example: `AsyncStorage.setItem('foo','bar');`  in react-native.

Comment: You should be able to do this. Did you get any errors when you tried it?

Comment: I was not able to verify that yesterday, now I have verified it. It works.